# What is the difference between "sheer" and "utter" in the sense of enphasis if there is any whatsoever?

Tags: differences

English is not my first language.

I don’t know the difference between *sheer* and *utter* used for emphasis.

For example, instead “That’s utter nonsense” can I say “That’s sheer nonsense” instead?

Comment: Yes, you can say both. Offhand I would say that _utter nonsense_ is more common. The only place I can think of where there is a difference is when specifying something as the sole reason something happened in a specific way. “His success is down to sheer hard work”, or “You passed your test. Sheer dumb luck!”. _Utter_ would not normally be used in that sense.

Comment: Many words can be used before *nonsense* that result in the same effective meaning:  *utter, sheer, total, complete, absolute*  The difference between *sheer* and *utter* is that *sheer* means pure, unadulterated; while *utter* means *outermost, furthest away* in the sense that what is being said is so far from the truth that it can't get any farther.  Ultimately they both reduce to the same thing:  Reality(sense) is here, and what is being said is so far from that that there is no mixing of sense and "non-sense", it's pure nonsense, unadulterated by even the slightest bit of sense.

Answer (score 7):

Funnily enough, the primary meanings of these two words (very little vs. far away) are almost opposites. A *sheer dress* has very thin or transparent cloth; the *utter end* (outer end) of the country is far out at the border.

- Something is *sheer nonsense* if it is just nonsense, with no trace of reason.
- Something is *utter nonsense* if it is extreme nonsense, beyond just ordinary nonsense.

Consequently, *sheer and utter nonsense* (a common phrase) is extreme nonsense with no trace of reason. Normally the two adjectives will essentially be synonyms when used with *nonsense*, but it's possible to come up with examples where strictly speaking only one or the other applies. (Not that anyone would notice!)

- "Bla bla oops gobbledygook helter skelter!"
- "Quick! quoth the hat-maker, Let's paint my colourless green ideas a presidential black ere the DHS fondles the aforementioned furious terrorist baby sleeper into a saturated explosion!"

I would argue that the first sentence is sheer nonsense but not utter nonsense. It's just a sequence of funny sounding words with no apparent connection between them. But there is nothing extreme about it. It could work as the refrain of a song.

I would call the second sentence utter nonsense but not sheer nonsense. I didn't think much about it when I wrote it, other than including lots of clues towards a non-existent hidden meaning. It's not sheer nonsense because it's actually quite political and you can't say that about sheer nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Hans with regard to the adjective.  It is much easier to see the difference in the derived adverbs:

*My answer may be utterly useless, but it will never be sheerly useless!*